# How to change foreground color of selected Expander inside DataGrid TemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a problem with changing foreground color of `Expander` by using `IsSelected` property. I'm using code below, which works fine with `Background`  property, but for some reason it doesn't work with `Foreground`.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="MediumSlateBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

I added a few another fields and result is pretty strange: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUvND.jpg)

As you can see, even `Label` *seems* broken and only standard `TextColumn` and `TemplateColumn` with TextBlock inside it changed their foreground, though all of them applied a purple background. I think, the case may be that the `Foreground` property from `Trigger` is attached to the same property only inside some objects, but I'm clearly too young to understand how this works.

Would be grateful for any help. Here is the code of my DataGrid Columns if it will be useful to you:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <!--Field with "Data in TextColumn"-->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="TextColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="170"/>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TextBlock" Width="150">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>Data in TextBlock</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Label" Width="150">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label>Data in Label</Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Expander" Width="250">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="Inside could be some objects"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Have a look: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8849add2-3ce0-4f0c-bfca-92defe0d8362/changing-forecolro-of-datagridtemlatecolumns-textboxes?forum=wpf. Especially "This Style uses a DataTrigger because the IsSelected Property of the DataGridCells might not always be up to date"

Comment: @BoppityBop, thanks a lot, it wokrs perfectly! Can you please make this comment like answer on the question so I can vote up and mark it as solution? It might be useful for another people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8849add2-3ce0-4f0c-bfca-92defe0d8362/changing-forecolro-of-datagridtemlatecolumns-textboxes?forum=wpf

It seems more appropriate style is:

```
<TextBox.Style>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
 <Setter Property="Foreground" 
    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=Foreground}" />
 </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

Comment: Can you also replace this code with the code above which consists of 5 lines? Because only first part of the Karsten163 answer change the color ;(

Comment: if _that_ fixed it then you shouldve better written styles for each templated column element ie label, expander.. because what works now is basically a hack. there is textbox somewhere down the visual tree in label and expander templates. i dont think its too bad - i dont think they will be replaced with something other than textbox. but academically speaking this is a hack